# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, cucumber

I am getting the "`cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`" while running my JUnit test case for Selenium with Cucumber.

I have created the maven project with feature file, step definition java file and test runner java class.

This is my feature file:

```
Feature: Free CRM Login Feature


#without Examples Keyword
#Scenario: Free CRM Login Test Scenario
#
#Given user is already on Login Page
#When title of login page is Free CRM
#Then user enters "naveenk" and "test@123"
#Then user clicks on login button
#Then user is on home page


#with Examples Keyword
Scenario Outline: Free CRM Login Test Scenario

Given user is already on Login Page
When title of login page is Free CRM
Then user enters "<username>" and "<password>"
Then user clicks on login button
Then user is on home page
Then Close the browser




Examples:
    | username | password |
    | naveenk  | test@123 |
    |  tom     | test456  |
```

My TestRunner.java:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.multiply_automation_testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

/**
 * @author BoMaseko
 *
 */

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="C:\\Users\\bomaseko\\eclipse-workspace\\multiply-website-automation\\src\\main\\java\\com\\multiply_automation_features\\multiply-login.feature"
        ,glue= {"C:\\Users\\bomaseko\\eclipse-workspace\\multiply-website-automation\\src\\main\\java\\com\\multiply_automation_stepDefinitions\\LoginStepDefinition"},
        plugin= {"pretty", "html:test-output"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

and my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>multiply-website-automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>multiply-website-automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>multiply-website-automation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I am getting this below error when I try to execute the JUnit test cases:

`cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader, io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)`

Comment: do not mix & match versions in cucumber dependencies. Use the same version for cucumber-core, cucumber-jvm, cucumber - junit.

Comment: Hi RadioJava thanks for your response, but the dependencies you mentioned are far apart in terms of versions

Comment: Can you add your step definitions and the complete stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the route of the features starting only from src and ending with the last directory:

```
src\\main\\java\\com\\multiply_automation_features
```

and for glue, just leave the directory where your test java files are located:

```
multiply_automation_stepDefinitions
```